# Prevent changes on radio button checked?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, radio-button

When i change the checked into another radio button, i wanna show a message and when user answers no, i want there will be any changing in my form but in my case i do get any changes.

In a word., is there any way to prevent checked changes on radio button with message box?

here it is come of my code and i put it in event `checked == false`

```
If lblGrandTotal.Text <> "0" Then
      If MessageBox.Show("?", "Pertanyaan", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.No Then
         rbPenjualan.Checked = True
         rbPenjualan.CausesValidation = False
      Else
         lvNota.Clear()
         lblGrandTotal.Text = "0"
         statuscekjual = False
      End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting the code in the `MouseDown` event for the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) and check the button back conditionally